# Invoking parse_date on an empty dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime

I am using the following to read a csv file:-

```
seller_in = pd.read_csv(seller_file, names=["MID", "START_DAY"], sep='\t', parse_dates=[1])
```

If the seller_file contains some data, then `seller_in['START_DAY']` returns `Name: START_DAY, Length: 326, dtype: datetime64[ns]`

However, if the seller_file is an empty file, then  `seller_in['START_DAY']` returns `Series([], Name: START_DAY, dtype: object)`

Why is this happening? Does `parse_date` not enforce datetype dtypes on empty csv read. If not, is there any way to enforce that the START_DAY columns is a datetime dtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
seller_in = pd.read_csv(seller_file, names=["MID", "START_DAY"], sep='\t')
seller_in['START_DAY'] = pd.to_datetime(seller_in['START_DAY'])
```

Sample:

```
seller_in = pd.DataFrame({'START_DAY':[]})
seller_in['START_DAY'] = pd.to_datetime(seller_in['START_DAY'])
print (seller_in.dtypes)
START_DAY    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this via dtypes?

Comment: I think no, `df.dtypes` are only for check dtypes